# Date time validation in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, validation, datetime

Can anyone help me on how can I validate given DateTime between two DateTime using vb.net?

the given DateTime must not in between the two DateTime..

Answer (score 4):

You can compare [date instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) the same way you would compare numbers as they override the `LessThan`, `LessThanOrEqual`, `GreaterThan` and `GreaterThanOrEqual` operators:

```
Dim minDate = New DateTime(2009, 4, 17)
Dim maxDate = New DateTime(2011, 4, 17)
Dim selectedDate = New DateTime(2010, 4, 17)

If selectedDate > minDate And selectedDate < maxDate Then
    Console.WriteLine("selected date is valid")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("selected date is invalid")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare%28VS.71%29.aspx)

```
Dim date1 As New DateTime(100)
Dim date2 As New DateTime(200)
Dim workingDate As New DateTime(150)    

If DateTime.Compare(workingDate , date1) >= 0 AND DateTime.Compare(workingDate , date2) <= 0 Then
    Console.WriteLine("Between")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Between")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dt As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
If dt < CDate("2010-04-01") Or dt > CDate("2010-04-10") Then
    MessageBox.Show("Date is not in the first 10 days of April so is ok")
End If
```